# Error in R density bw.SJ

Tags: r, density-plot

I am using the density function with the SJ method:

```
rdat <- rnorm(111111)
density(rdat, bw = "sj")
Error in bw.SJ(x, method = "ste") : sample is too sparse to find TD
```

It seems to fail on large sample, stating the sample is too sparse. This has been asked before [here](https://stat.ethz.ch/pipermail/r-help/2008-April/158701.html), but has anything changed since 2008? Are there any fixes out there for this/ workarounds?

Edit: Limit seems to be `46341`

Answer (score 0):

This bug was fixed in R 3.4.0 (April, 2017).

Here is the relevant fragment from [svnlog](http://developer.r-project.org/R_svnlog_2017):

```
r71965 | maechler | 2017-01-13 04:30:18 -0600 (Fri, 13 Jan 2017) | 1 line
Changed paths:
   M /trunk/doc/NEWS.Rd
   M /trunk/src/library/stats/R/bandwidths.R
   M /trunk/src/library/stats/man/bandwidth.Rd
   M /trunk/src/library/stats/man/density.Rd
   M /trunk/src/library/stats/src/bandwidths.c

fix bw.SJ() integer overflow for large n
```

Here is the corresponding commit in a mirror of R source code: https://github.com/wch/r-source/commit/5af0f7200128315392cf813127a654153b5e7739

Here is the fragment from [R 3.4.0 change log](https://cran.r-project.org/bin/windows/base/old/3.4.0/NEWS.R-3.4.0.html):

> Bandwidth selectors `bw.ucv()`, `bw.bcv()` and `bw.SJ()` now avoid integer overflow for large sample sizes.