# Plotting predicted posterior distribution of a binomial model

Tags: r, ggplot2, logistic-regression, bayesian, brms

I was wondering if anyone had any experience with plotting predictions of a multivariate binomial model with brms? I will only provide the code for one response variable below.

All I get is this warning message:

> Warning message:
> Computation failed in `stat_eye()`
> Caused by error in `bw.SJ()`:
> ! sample is too sparse to find TD

```
My_model <- brm(FutureReproduction~ Reproductive_success+ Age 
     + Precipitation+ Scaled_Leg_index 
     + Reproductive_success*Age
     + (1 | ID),
     family = bernoulli()) 

condition <-expand.grid("Age" = (c(3, 4, 5, 6, 7,8, 9, 10, 11)),
                        Year = 2011,
                        ID = 3,
                        Precipitation= 0,
                        Leg_index= 0,
                        Reproductive_success = c(0, 1))


Model_prediction <- condition %>% 
  add_predicted_rvars(My_model, allow_new_levels = TRUE, re_formula = NA, newdata = .) %>% 
  mutate(Reproductive_success = factor(ifelse(Reproductive_success == 1, "Yes", "No"), levels = c("No", "Yes"))) 


> Model_prediction 
# A tibble: 18 × 7
     Age  Year    ID       Precipitation      Leg_index  Reproductive_success  prediction[,"Jumpheight"]  [,"Sprintspeed"] [,"Future Reproduction"] [,"Survival"]
   <dbl> <dbl> <dbl>              <dbl>            <dbl> <fct>                        <rvar[,1]>    <rvar[,1]>          <rvar[,1]>      <rvar[,1]>
 1     3  2011     3                  0                0 No                          21.33 ± 5.9    2.41 ± 1.8        0.261 ± 0.44     0.97 ± 0.18
 2     4  2011     3                  0                0 No                          10.63 ± 6.0    1.57 ± 1.8        0.230 ± 0.42     0.97 ± 0.17
 3     5  2011     3                  0                0 No                           4.60 ± 5.9    1.03 ± 1.8        0.202 ± 0.40     0.97 ± 0.18
 4     6  2011     3                  0                0 No                           2.49 ± 5.9    0.74 ± 1.8        0.188 ± 0.39     0.96 ± 0.19
 5     7  2011     3                  0                0 No                           2.63 ± 5.9    0.67 ± 1.8        0.168 ± 0.37     0.96 ± 0.19
 6     8  2011     3                  0                0 No                           3.59 ± 5.9    0.64 ± 1.8        0.153 ± 0.36     0.95 ± 0.22
 7     9  2011     3                  0                0 No                           5.12 ± 5.9    0.66 ± 1.8        0.148 ± 0.36     0.93 ± 0.25
 8    10  2011     3                  0                0 No                           6.88 ± 6.0    0.69 ± 1.8        0.136 ± 0.34     0.90 ± 0.29
 9    11  2011     3                  0                0 No                           8.97 ± 6.4    0.79 ± 1.9        0.134 ± 0.34     0.85 ± 0.35
10     3  2011     3                  0                0 Yes                          9.54 ± 6.6   -0.66 ± 2.0        0.029 ± 0.17     0.91 ± 0.28
11     4  2011     3                  0                0 Yes                          5.97 ± 5.9   -0.41 ± 1.8        0.025 ± 0.16     0.93 ± 0.25
12     5  2011     3                  0                0 Yes                          2.89 ± 6.1   -0.71 ± 1.8        0.022 ± 0.15     0.94 ± 0.23
13     6  2011     3                  0                0 Yes                          0.46 ± 6.0   -1.37 ± 1.8        0.018 ± 0.13     0.95 ± 0.23
14     7  2011     3                  0                0 Yes                         -1.18 ± 6.0   -2.11 ± 1.8        0.016 ± 0.13     0.95 ± 0.23
15     8  2011     3                  0                0 Yes                         -2.21 ± 6.1   -2.56 ± 1.8        0.017 ± 0.13     0.94 ± 0.24
16     9  2011     3                  0                0 Yes                         -2.53 ± 6.1   -2.63 ± 1.8        0.018 ± 0.13     0.92 ± 0.27
17    10  2011     3                  0                0 Yes                         -2.30 ± 6.2   -2.54 ± 1.8        0.017 ± 0.13     0.89 ± 0.32
18    11  2011     3                  0                0 Yes                         -1.54 ± 6.4   -2.22 ± 1.9        0.019 ± 0.14     0.86 ± 0.35

#Plot

Model_prediction %>% 
  ggplot(aes(x = Reproductive_success , ydist = .prediction[,"Future Reproduction"]) )+
  stat_eye()

Warning message:
Computation failed in `stat_eye()`
Caused by error in `bw.SJ()`:
! sample is too sparse to find TD
```

I used the exact same approach for my other figures with gaussian distribution (continuous response variables) and had no issues

Comment: So this can't be recreated for anyone else because we can't actually fit the model, and therefore can't actually get any predictions to try.
I'm not familiar enough with some of the processes you are using to know how they actually look in terms of outputs, so if you could post some of the intermediate steps that might make debugging easier. For example, what is going into the ydist value, i.e. what is the output of .prediction[,"Future Reproduction"]? Pipes are awesome for a lot, but not very fun to try to navigate when you need to debug through multiple complex steps all in one line.

Comment: Hello! I output of .prediction[,"Future Reproduction"] is the Future reproduction column that you see in the Model_prediction tibble, or the logistic regression's prediction for how this response variable. 

When I created the dummy data set to simulate the model's prediction, you can see that an individual who did not reproduce at age 3 has a predicted probability of reproducing in the following year of  26.1% (0.261 ± 0.44), stored as an rvar. Had that same individual reproduce at age 3, we would see a future reproduction probability of 2.9% (0.029 ± 0.17)

Comment: Hm, ok, I don't have enough experience with these specific packages to help, so sorry about that. But I will just flag one other thing before I bail. Think about what those +- values entail, and maybe look into how those actually being calculated to make sure your model is performing right. Given that interval you could have probabilities less than 0. Not sure if that is just an issue with how those posteriors are being represented within the data frame or not, but just the place I found in the data that doesn't quite make sense.

Comment: Also potentially look into how large those objects from the posteriors actually are. Might somehow actually line up with the known issue of bw.sj not liking large samples. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36227614/error-in-r-density-bw-sj